# jquery autocomplete wrong view

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

What's wrong with this code? When I type a word, suggestions do not appear in correct form.

Is there anything else I should load?

Updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div class="list">
        <div class="item">
            <input type="hidden" class="user-id" id="h1"/>
            <input type="text" class="user-name" id="t1"/>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>

<script>
var users = [
    {"label":"User 1","value":"User 1","userId":1},
    {"label":"User 2","value":"User 2","userId":2}
];

$(".user-name").autocomplete({
    source: users,
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 0, 
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just needed one line additional code:
found the answer:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when adding

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

see this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bqujj/102/)